# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Each request requires the same not null build mode to be set

Tags: android

I just update my android studio to the latest version. After this action, when I create new empty activity project, I make project for test but I get following IDE internal error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Each request requires the same not null build mode to be set
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleBuildInvokerImpl.executeAssembleTasks(GradleBuildInvokerImpl.kt:166)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleBuildInvokerImpl.assemble(GradleBuildInvokerImpl.kt:212)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleBuildInvokerImpl.assemble(GradleBuildInvokerImpl.kt:206)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.actions.MakeGradleProjectAction.doPerform(MakeGradleProjectAction.java:45)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.actions.AndroidStudioGradleAction.actionPerformed(AndroidStudioGradleAction.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.doPerformActionOrShowPopup(ActionUtil.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.lambda$performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks$4(ActionUtil.java:294)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:337)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:294)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$performAction$4(ActionMenuItem.java:293)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:227)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.performAction(ActionMenuItem.java:286)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$new$0(ActionMenuItem.java:67)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$3(ActionMenuItem.java:109)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:105)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:109)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:546)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:578)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6656)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3385)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6421)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5026)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2804)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:788)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:761)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:759)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:758)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:918)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:840)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:763)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:450)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:791)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:449)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:624)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:881)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:493)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
```

it is necessary to mention that in terminal section of android studio I get the following note

Cannot open local terminal.
Failed to start [powershell.exe] in e:\my_app .
See IDE log for details

best regards

I have checked gradle  and see nothing unusual  .I expected to show output on AVD (an empty page...)